# SDL_GL_SwapBuffers Segfault

Tags: opengl, sdl

I'm getting a segfault that GDB says is coming from SDL_GL_SwapBuffers. However, I can't imagine why. The SDL documentation mentions no specific pre-conditions for calling swapBuffers except that double buffering be allowed. Is this an option I have to turn on while initializing OpenGL or is this a hardware capability thing?

My code:

http://pastie.org/859721

(Ignore the unused variables, strange comments and other things. I haven't prettied this up at all. :P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_GL_SwapBuffers) says:

> **Description**
>
> Swap the OpenGL buffers, if
> double-buffering is supported.

You are using `SDL_GL_SwapBuffers()` without enabling double-buffering.

---

```
SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 32, SDL_DOUBLEBUF | SDL_HWSURFACE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you mixing gl and SDL calls?  Seems like SDL should give you an OpenGL context and make it active, then you could call glSwapBuffers.

Comment: This is fairly common...and glSwapBuffers doesn't exist that I can find. There's glutSwapBuffers, and glxSwapBuffers....swapping buffers is more of a function of the windowing toolkit (SDL in this case).

Comment: ack, you're right!  Too much time using a toolkit that puts wgl* and gl* functions into a single class and strips the prefix, I guess.